# Enviar email como Feedback en Android

Tags: java, android

Necesito implementar la funcionalidad de `feedback` en Android, que el usuario al accionar la acción se envíe un correo electrónico, con la app disponible, pero pre-configurado con el email a recibir el email.

Answer (score 0):

Buscando por [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent) he encontrado la solución más fácil.

La mejor opción es usar librería de compatibilidad `ShareCompat` para crear el intent.

```
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
    .setType("message/rfc822")
    .addEmailTo("direccion@email.com")
    .setSubject("titulo del email")
    .setText("cuerpo del mensaje")
    //.setHtmlText(body) //Si se quiere usar HTML en el cuerpo del mensaje
    .setChooserTitle("Enviar Feedback con")
    .startChooser();
```

Si se quiere detectar si existe una app compatible para enviar el email, remplazar el `.startChooser()` por `.createChooserIntent()`

```
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
    .setType("message/rfc822")
    .addEmailTo("direccion@email.com")
    .setSubject("titulo del email")
    .setText("cuerpo del mensaje")
    //.setHtmlText(body) //Si se quiere usar HTML en el cuerpo del mensaje
    .setChooserTitle("Enviar Feedback con")
    .createChooserIntent();

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    } else { /*imposible enviar feedback*/}
```

Si se quiere saber más sobre el `ShareCompat` dejo tutorial [Sharing Content The Easy Way using ShareCompat](https://www.niyati.com/blog/android-sharecompat/)